# Does microk8s allow pulling from insecure registry?

Tags: docker, docker-image, microk8s, docker-pull

For docker pull we can do something like the following so it can pull from a local registry by running `docker pull localhost:32000/hello:latest`.

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : [
      "localhost:32000"
  ]
}
```

Is there similar config can be done, such when running cmd like:

```
microk8s ctr image pull localhost:32000/hello:latest
```

it doesn't run into `server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`?

Answer (score 2):

From https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-private:

```
sudo bash
umask 770
AUTHORITY='localhost:32000'
mkdir -p "/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/certs.d/${AUTHORITY}"
cat <<EOF >"/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/certs.d/${AUTHORITY}/hosts.toml"
server = "http://${AUTHORITY}"

[host."${AUTHORITY}"]
capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
EOF
microk8s stop
microk8s start
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctr` flag `--plain-text` to use insecure protocol. [Source code](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/25d7f907c03a58b5fa30c6f90c3a36aa308e124c/cmd/ctr/commands/commands.go#L58)

```
microk8s ctr image pull --plain-text localhost:32000/hello:latest
```

Comment: now you should use --plain-http